# How to pass an awk variable to a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How can I pass an `awk` variable to a `bash` command run within `awk`?

I'm using awk to calculate a running sum of threads for each of a certain process, but then I want to use each pid to access the `/proc/$pid` filesystem.

The line marked **broken** below is incorrect, because `$pid` is non-existent.

How can I export the awk variable `pid` to the shell command I get `awk` to run?

*(Line breaks added for readability)*

```
$ ps -ALf | grep $PROC | grep -v grep | \         # get each pid
    awk '{threads[$2]+=1} END \                   # count num threads per pid
         { \
           for (pid in threads) \
              "cat /proc/$pid/cwd"|getline cwd; \ # get 'cwd' (**broken**)
               print cwd ": " threads[pid] \      # display 'cwd' and num threads
         }'
```

Comment: Why not do the whole lot in awk?

Comment: Don't do `grep ...|grep -v ...|awk ...` as awk can do the job of grep(s). On linux you can use `ps -C $PROC` to show only a specificly named process(es).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole lot in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) without any `grep`s link this:

```
% ps -ALf | awk -v proc="${PROC}" '
$0 ~ proc && !/awk/ {
    threads[$2] += 1
}
END {
    for (pid in threads) {
        "readlink /proc/" pid "/cwd" | getline dir
        printf "%d: %d %s\n", pid,  threads[pid], dir
        dir=""
    }
}'
```

A few things worth noting:

- `-v proc="${PROC}"` assigns the environment variable `${PROC}` to an `awk` variable, `proc`
- `"readlink /proc/" pid "/cwd"` concatenates the three strings. There's no need for any concatenation operator in `awk`.
- `dir=""` resets the `dir` variable, in case the symlink is not readable the next time around the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cat `/proc/$pid/cwd` it is a symlink to a directory. One way to resolve symlinks is with `readlink` from coreutils.

Here is a working example using bits from *TrueY* and *Barmer*:

```
ps -C $PROC | 
awk '{ t[$1] } END { for(p in t) { "readlink -f /proc/" p "/cwd" | getline c; print c } }'
```

A couple of things to notice:

- Pipe doubles as a line continuation character.
- It is enough to refer to an array entry to create it (`t[$1]`).

Answer (score 2):

awk doesn't do variable interpolation inside strings, you just concatenate the variable with the strings (just like you do in the `print` statement).

```
awk '{threads[$2]+=1} END                    # count num threads per pid
     { 
       for (pid in threads) 
          ("cat /proc/" pid "/cwd")|getline cwd;  # get 'cwd' (**broken**)
           print cwd ": " threads[pid]       # display 'cwd' and num threads
     }'
```

You also don't need all those backslashes. Newlines inside a quoted string don't need to be escaped (and some of them weren't even before newlines, there were comments after them).